# DDMathParser (iOS 5): How to set radians versus degrees?

Tags: ios

DDMathParser:  How do I let the parser know whether the input to a function, i.e. the sin function, is in degrees or radians?  If the "mode" is degrees, I want to execute :  sin(n *2 *pi /360), or just sin(n) if the "mode" is radians.

I can't get the class method in _DDFunctionUtilities to recognize any properties defined anywhere else.

Comment: Are you trying to set a mode, or read a mode? And can you link to documentation for the library you are using, and show the relevant API and your code? I don't readily see anything at the github page about a mode... perhaps it's just simply one or the other?

Comment: Regarding your last sentence: the methods in `_DDFunctionUtilities` return blocks, and those blocks take a `DDMathEvaluator` as one of the arguments.  That's where you'd be looking for "properties defined [elsewhere]".

Comment: To all those interested: DDMathParser now allows you to change the `angleMeasurementMode` from Radians to Degrees.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that the library uses C's math.h sin() function, which is quite simply always in radians. See (if you are interested) section 7.12.4.6 of [the C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) (large PDF)

For your app to provide both as options, you can achieve this in many, many ways. The best way depends on your app. If I were making a calculator with modes, I would likely have a calculator instance (model) which has a @property for the sin/rad mode, then my views would have a button connected to a viewController method `-(IBAction)toggleAngleMeasurementUnit:(UIButton) sender`, which calls the appropriate method on the calc object (it is also responsible for delegating most other button presses. Then inside your calculator class, ANY code which uses these values checks the mode first and does appropriate conversion (Or, perhaps more compellingly, the mode ONLY affects the accessor methods, and the value is stored in a canonical way (i.e. always radians), which would allow me to do 30 degrees + pi radians = ?

Comment: +1 (DDMathParser author here) this is correct. The arguments to the trigonometric functions all want or return things in radians, as appropriate. You can convert things to degrees with the `rtod` function (and its inverse `dtor`). Also, the degree sign (`°`) does the same thing as `dtor`.

Comment: This may be true, but just as in graphing/scientific calculators, my user may want to input a number in degrees, and get an answer in degrees (alot of engineering analyses, RF etc, are done in degrees)...if someone wants to enter 1 + 3*sin(30) WITHOUT using the degree symbol...I wanted to implement a MODE (degrees or radians) so that depending on the mode the program is in, either sin(n) is run, or sin(2*pi/360*n) is run...a simple if statement.

Comment: I've mentioned a few ideas in my answer. This kind of state management is an integral part of almost any app.

Comment: @greydient interesting thought.  It's possible to hack up DDMathParser to do this, but it would be a bit of a change.  I'll investigate adding an "angle measurement mode" setting in there somewhere.

Comment: @greydient I've updated DDMathParser to allow you to change between Radians and Degrees mode.

Comment: @DaveDeLong:  Thanks for making the update - you won't regret it.  I had worked around this buy parsing every string before submitting it to your evaluator...my code will be much cleaner now

Comment: @greydient you're welcome! Please file an issue on Github if you run in to problems with it.